# How can I resize my one linux partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I am trying to install win10 and am currently in the process of creating a partition. The problem is that I currently have 3 partitions(esp, os, ubuntu). I should mention that I only have one hard drive.
I am trying to resize the ubuntu labeled partition but it is locked. Can I unmount it safely? if not, how can I resize it?

Comment: In UEFI mode Windows wants lots of partitions. Best just to make unallocated space. Make sure drive is gpt, not old MBR(msdos) as Windows will only install in  UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. It will use existing ESP for its boot files. Be sure to boot Windows installer in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: And in addition to what @oldfred wrote, use a live environment to do this. Use the usb stick you used to install Ubuntu and choose 'try Ubuntu'.